# Help with function inside of event using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a CheckBox list and I want to get the number of items selected when a checkbox is checked/unchecked.

checkCount is always 0.  It seems to me like checkCount is getting assigned when the page loads and the getCheckCount function is never called again.  Why doesn't this work and how can I get the event to have an up to date checkCount?  Thank you.

```
   $(function () {
        $('#<%=cblInterests.ClientID%> input').click(function () {
            var checkCount = getCheckCount();
            alert(checkCount);
            return checkCount < 2;
        });
    });        

    function getCheckCount() {
        return $('#<%=cblInterests.ClientID%>').children('input:checked').length;
    }
```

Comment: Are the checkboxes directly beneath #client-id? If not, use "find" instead of "children"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change) event, not the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click) event.

Comment: Same issue, the count is still always 0.

Comment: It would help if you could show your markup. But, try changing `.children(...)` to `.find(...)`.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time, please post the relevant HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(function () {
        $('#<%=cblInterests.ClientID%>').delegate('input', 'change', function () {
            var checkCount = getCheckCount();
            alert(checkCount);
            return checkCount < 2;
        });
    });        

    function getCheckCount() {
        return $('#<%=cblInterests.ClientID%> input:checked').length;
    }
```

the use of .delegate (or .live) allows you to add inputs on the fly.